# M (PowerQuery), set the value of a non-primitive variable in a let statement

Tags: excel, powerquery, m, let

I'm writing a custom M Language (PowerQuery in Excel) function to query a RESTful interface. This interface has a large number of optional parameters.

Starting with a simple case- I handle an optional `limit` passed as a simple (primitive) value as follows-

```
/* 
 * RESTful API Get from the named endpoint
 */
(endpoint as text, optional limit) =>
let
    // query limit
    // If limit is supplied as a number, it will be converted to text
    // If limit is not supplied it will be set to the value "1000"

    limit = if limit <> null then Text.From(limit) else "1000",
```

As the full API has many paramaters I wanted to use a Record to pass them to the function, but then I realised I don't know how to persuade M to write the default values into the parameter record.

I tried a couple of options.

1. Direct access-

```
(endpoint as text, optional params as record) =>
let
    params[limit] = if (params[limit] = null) then "1000",
```

the result is a syntax error-'Token equal expected'

2. Merging the new value of limit as a Record with "&"

```
(endpoint as text, optional params as record) =>
let
    params = params & if params[limit] = null then [limit = "1000"] else [],
```

result syntax error-'Token Literal expected'

I'm clearly missing something about the syntax rules for `let` statements, I know I need a `variable = value` assignment, and it looks as if putting anything other than a plain variable name on the LHS to write elements inside a structured value is not allowed, but i'm not sure how to acieve this otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want here, but to create a List of Records where some Records have a default parameter and others do not, you could try something like:

```
(newParams as record) => 
let 
    default = [limit=1000, param2=2, param3=3],
    final = Record.Combine({default, newParams})   
in 
    final
```

With regard to `Record.Combine`, the beauty is that the right hand record will override the left hand record if both are present; and it will just add to it if nothing is present.

So something like:

```
let
    Source = [limit=400, param3="x", param7=246],
    conv = fnParams(Source)
in
    conv
```

**=>**

[image]

Depending on the required format of your output string, you can build it using `List.Accumulate`. eg:

```
let
    Source = [limit=400, param3="x", param7=246],
    conv = fnParams(Source),
    list = List.Accumulate(List.Zip({Record.FieldNames(conv), Record.ToList(conv)}), "",
        (state,current) =>state & "&" & current{0} & "=" & Text.From(current{1}) )
in
    list
```

**=>** `&limit=400&param2=2&param3=x&param7=246`

Comment: I'm still a little vague on exactly how the functional nature of M affects parameter passing (when/if parameters can be written to or replaced) but your solution is very elegant @ron-rosenfeld, thank you.  I need to remember to go looking for function-style equivalents (e.g. Record.Combine() ) for the statement syntax in M.

The second half of your reply is exactly what I was going to be trying to do next (convert the parameter values to a URL parameter string) so thank you for answering the question I had not even asked yet!

Comment: @Incans I am still learning also.  The MS documentation doesn't seem to document more than very basic stuff.  Online blogs can be very useful, along with trial and error, in trying to figure out the fine points of some of the functions.